# PHP - Multimentional array - If same value in array, change all values except first

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to change values of an array if one of the value is several times into and change by `null` the duplicate values exept the first.

I have this array:
$array =

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'data-time-start' => int 0
      'data-time-end' => int 5
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'data-time-start' => int 6
      'data-time-end' => int 10
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'data-time-start' => int 11
      'data-time-end' => int 15
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 16
      'data-time-end' => int 20
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'data-time-start' => int 21
      'data-time-end' => int 25
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 30
      'data-time-end' => int 35
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' =>  null
      'data-time-start' => int 40
      'data-time-end' => int 45
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 45
      'data-time-end' => int 60
```

In this example I have two times `'id' = int 1` and three times `'id' = int 3` . What I would like to do is to keep the first ID but set other duplicate IDs to NULL and return an array like this:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'data-time-start' => int 0
      'data-time-end' => int 5
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'data-time-start' => int 6
      'data-time-end' => int 10
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => null
      'data-time-start' => int 11
      'data-time-end' => int 15
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 16
      'data-time-end' => int 20
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'data-time-start' => int 21
      'data-time-end' => int 25
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => null
      'data-time-start' => int 30
      'data-time-end' => int 35
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => null
      'data-time-start' => int 40
      'data-time-end' => int 45
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => null
      'data-time-start' => int 45
      'data-time-end' => int 60
```

Tried with that but nothing happened...

```
var_dump(setNulForDuplicatesInArray($array, 'id'))

function setNulForDuplicatesInArray($arr, $keyToFind)
    {
        $newArr = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
            if (in_array($arr[$i], $newArr))
                $newArr[$i][$keyToFind] = null;
            else
                $newArr[] = $arr[$i];
        }
        return $newArr;
    }
```

array() is the same...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create another container that will be used for checking if that particular ID has already been taken. In every iteration, you'll have to check it. If it has been already inside the container, then set that id to null. Rough example:

```
$temp = array(); // temporary container
foreach($array as &$a) {
    if(!isset($temp[$a['id']])) { // if this id isn't here yet
        $temp[$a['id']] = $a; // push it inside
    } else {
        $a['id'] = null; // if its already taken, set it to null
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nQxABn)

Comment: Okay for explainations but your function return 'null'

Comment: @Zagloo i don't know how you're using this but it works fine http://codepad.viper-7.com/nQxABn

Comment: oh sorry... I put your code in a function and return $temp instead of $array... Thanks for all :) !!

Comment: @Zagloo here's an application on your function http://codepad.viper-7.com/pdz2S5 im glad this helped